# Estoy queriendo que mi Verificación de edad se quite al comprobar la edad

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito ayuda, estoy queriendo que mi Verificación de edad se quite al comprobar la edad y que cuando se refresque la pagina ya no se siga viendo, (mi codigo funciona pero al momento de recargar la pagina vuelve a aparecer el div)

```
$(".LangHref").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        if ($('.Edad-seleccion').remove()) {
            $('.home_2').removeClass('hidden');
            comenzar();
          return false;
        } else {
        }
    });
```

```
<div class="Edad-seleccion">
            <div class="info-edad">
                <p class="text">¿Eres mayor de edad?</p>
                <p class="text">You're of age?</p>
                <div class="buttons-to-choose">
                    <a href="#" class="LangHref"><button id="yes" class="button-choose">Si</button></a> 
                    <a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/"><button id="no"  
                    class="button-choose">No</button></a>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Al recargar la página se reinicia, ya que no estás guardando la selección en el lado del cliente. Considera almacenarlo en una cookie y el localStorage de tu navegador

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor haz el [tour] y consulta [ask] - te ayudará a mejorar la pregunta. De momento no haces algo para que haya información persistente. Si la información de validación no se guarda para ser leída al recargar no cuentas con un mecanismo para controlar modificaciones en dicho momento.

Comment: Hola puedes guardar una varialbe en el localStorage y cuando refresques la pagina leerla.